# Прочитать файл и записать данные в определенную строку

Tags: golang, ос

***Как мне записать данные в 8 строку?***

Думал и пробовал делать так `\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n` чтоб перейти на 8 линию и записать уже туда данные. Но так делаются только отступы и отступается 8 строк от последней строки в файле тоесть `</html>`.

**Код:**

```
f, err := os.OpenFile("public_html.html", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()

if _, err = f.WriteString("\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"+"Hello"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Получается:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    Very fast!
 </body>
</html>







Hello
```

А нужно записать вместе с `Very fast!` Который расположен на 8 строке. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Наверное читать построчно, считать строки и просто менять 8ю (index 7 ;)). И заново записывать в файл все строки построчно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример https://play.golang.org/p/jEITDk9fkt

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    lines := `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    Very fast!
 </body>
</html>
`
    file := bytes.NewReader([]byte(lines))
    // defer close real file

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    c := 1
    for scanner.Scan() {
        var s string
        if c == 8 {
            s = "Hello " + scanner.Text()
        } else {
            s = scanner.Text()
        }

        // записывать в новый файл построчно
        // меняйте os.Stdout на файл, буфер и тд и тп
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, s)

        c++
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Только у меня одна проблему с чтением файла и записью в него. Ссылка - https://pastebin.com/uCRxpXEj не могу понять в чем дело, компилируется без ошибок, но я так подозреваю что ошибка в fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, s)

Comment: там всё немного проще строка 11 `scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)` всё остальное можно удалить (с 4ой по 10ю строки).  и обязательно проверяйте все ошибки и закрывайте файл.

Comment: изменил как вы сказали, но у меня не происходит запись в файл

Comment: немного переписал должно работать https://pastebin.com/i5W8brYC